# In my rails erb, how can i replace an ajax button_to by a link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, link-to

I have the following button :

> <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(:product_id => product),
>   :remote => true %>

I want to replace it by a link_to containing an image with text on it.

I am ok with the HTML CSS part, but i want the request to be for line_items#create not for line_items#index

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of try and error i found that :

```
<%= link_to ("<div>Ajouter au panier</div>"+image_tag("some.jpg")).html_safe,
                                     line_items_path(:product_id => @product),
                                     :action => :create,
                                     :remote => true,:method => :post%>
```

It works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "Add to Cart", {:controller => "line_items", :action => :create}, :remote => true %>
```

And don't forget to update routes.rb too, e.g.:

```
get "/blablabla", :to => "line_items#create"
```